# How can I render a LIT web component that contains a slot into the document body?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit

How can I maintain the Shadow DOM behavior when using `createRenderRoot` to render a component in `document.body` and using slots?

In my current implementation, I am using `createRenderRoot` to set where my component should render, specifically in `document.body`. However, when I use slots, the component no longer behaves as expected, possibly because it is no longer using the Shadow DOM.

Is there a way to maintain the Shadow DOM behavior while using `createRenderRoot`?

Here is a playground to demonstrate the issue.
[Lit Playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#sample=docs%2Fcomponents%2Fshadowdom%2Frenderroot&project=W3sibmFtZSI6ImxpZ2h0LWRvbS50cyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge0xpdEVsZW1lbnQsIGh0bWx9IGZyb20gJ2xpdCc7XG5pbXBvcnQge2N1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnR9IGZyb20gJ2xpdC9kZWNvcmF0b3JzLmpzJztcblxuQGN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnQoJ2xpZ2h0LWRvbScpXG5leHBvcnQgY2xhc3MgTGlnaHREb20gZXh0ZW5kcyBMaXRFbGVtZW50IHtcbiAgcHJvdGVjdGVkIHJlbmRlcigpIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gaHRtbGBcbiAgICAgICAgPGRpdj4gQ3VzdG9tIHJlbmRlcmluZyA8c2xvdD48L3Nsb3Q-IHdpdGggYSBTTE9UIGluc2lkZS48L2Rpdj5cbiAgICAgIFxuICAgIGA7XG4gIH1cbiAgcHJvdGVjdGVkIGNyZWF0ZVJlbmRlclJvb3QoKSB7ICAgICBcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gZG9jdW1lbnQuYm9keVxuICB9XG59XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJpbmRleC5odG1sIiwiY29udGVudCI6IjwhRE9DVFlQRSBodG1sPlxuPGh0bWwgbGFuZz1cImVuXCI-XG4gIDxoZWFkPlxuICAgIDxtZXRhIGNoYXJzZXQ9XCJVVEYtOFwiIC8-XG4gICAgPG1ldGEgbmFtZT1cInZpZXdwb3J0XCIgY29udGVudD1cIndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCwgaW5pdGlhbC1zY2FsZT0xLjBcIiAvPlxuICAgIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vZGVmYXVsdC1yb290LmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG4gICAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPVwibW9kdWxlXCIgc3JjPVwiLi9saWdodC1kb20uanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbiAgICA8dGl0bGU-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)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Check it out here](https://lit.dev/playground/#sample=docs%2Fcomponents%2Fshadowdom%2Frenderroot&project=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-IHdpdGggYSBTTE9UIGluc2lkZS48L2Rpdj5cbiAgICBgXG5cbiAgICAgLy8gQXBwZW5kIGl0IHRvIHRoZSBzaGFkb3cgcm9vdFxuICAgICBzaGFkb3cuYXBwZW5kQ2hpbGQoZGl2KTtcbiAgICB9XG4gIHByb3RlY3RlZCBjcmVhdGVSZW5kZXJSb290KCkgeyAgICAgXG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHlcbiAgfVxufVxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxodG1sIGxhbmc9XCJlblwiPlxuICA8aGVhZD5cbiAgICA8bWV0YSBjaGFyc2V0PVwiVVRGLThcIiAvPlxuICAgIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9XCJ2aWV3cG9ydFwiIGNvbnRlbnQ9XCJ3aWR0aD1kZXZpY2Utd2lkdGgsIGluaXRpYWwtc2NhbGU9MS4wXCIgLz5cbiAgICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL2RlZmF1bHQtcm9vdC5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuICAgIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vbGlnaHQtZG9tLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG4gICAgPHRpdGxlPmxpdC1lbGVtZW50IGNvZGUgc2FtcGxlPC90aXRsZT5cbiAgICA8c3R5bGU-XG4gICAgICBwIHtcbiAgICAgICAgYm9yZGVyOiAxcHggZG90dGVkIGJsYWNrO1xuICAgICAgfVxuICAgIDwvc3R5bGU-XG4gIDwvaGVhZD5cbiAgPGJvZHk-XG4gICAgPHA-TVkgQk9EWSBTVEFSVDwvcD4gXG4gICAgPGRpdj5cbiAgICAgPGxpZ2h0LWRvbT5NeSBzbG90IGNvbnRlbnQ8L2xpZ2h0LWRvbT5cbiAgICA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgICA8cD5NWSBCT0RZIEVORDwvcD4gXG4gIDwvYm9keT5cbjwvaHRtbD5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0)

```js
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit';
import {customElement} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('light-dom')
export class LightDom extends LitElement {
  static shadowRootOptions = {...LitElement.shadowRootOptions, delegatesFocus: true, open: true};
  constructor() {
      super()
          
    // Create a shadow root
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

    // Create div and add slots
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = `
      <div> Custom rendering <slot></slot> with a SLOT inside.</div>
    `

     // Append it to the shadow root
     shadow.appendChild(div);
    }
  protected createRenderRoot() {     
    return document.body
  }
}
```